# What does "cause extra bleeding damage" actually mean?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Hack and Slash perk in the One-handed skill tree says that

> Attacks with war axes cause extra bleeding damage

What is bleeding damage?
Is it instant or damage over time?
Do undead take bleeding damage?

I love the flavor of using war axes but I want to know more about this perk before I take it.

Comment: Both the Skyrim wikia and Skyrim facebook community page have pre-release info stating it's damage over time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bleeding damage is a damage-over-time effect: each rank in *Hack and Slash* will do one to two extra points of damage every second for a few seconds. It's essentially a fast-acting poison.

As in Morrowind and Oblivion, undead like skeletons are unaffected by poisons and effects like these.